# How can I replay web requests on a production clone to control a release candidate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a critical Rails app running in production with a fairly standard setup: Rails 5 API, Puma, PostgreSQL, Sidekiq, Heroku. I also have a branch that involves risky database migrations and application code changes.

I'd like to clone the production setup and data to a dedicated staging environment and, for a few busy hours, run all production web requests on both environments to control the effect of this change on the data.

Things I thought about so far:

- this can't be only about replaying database logs, as changes happen at the application level
- some API requests schedule some Sidekiq jobs 1 minute in the future, so ideally this also triggers jobs real-time
- it'd be great if this was done at the Heroku router or application level instead of higher up the chain (DNS, load balancer etc.): I could see a Rake middleware in the main application that mirrors all requests to this production clone, or an `after_action` filter in select Rails controllers

A way for me to control these changes would be to look at errors raised by the production clone (application errors and database rollbacks).

Comment: Is the web / API interface identical between both versions? How much traffic are you looking at replaying?

Comment: i wrote a small go app that uses a heroku log-drain to replay traffic. it only replays get requests, but that was kinda on purpose. https://github.com/Jimdo/heroku-replayer-drain-go

Comment: @fylooi Identical API, and around 15 requests per minute

Comment: @phoet Interesting! Going to take a look at log-driven request replays